# Can error in digital signal be zero after filtering?

Tags: matlab, digital-filters

Can error in digital signal be zero after filtering? I have looked up online to know about this but I could not find a solution.

Comment: Welcome to SE.DSP. Could you elaborate a little more? What is the signal, what kind of filter? What do you call error?

Comment: x = -10:0.1:10;
A1 = sin(2*x + 2);
A2 = sin(5*x + 1);
y = 2.5*A1 + 1.4*A2;
y_noise = y + rand(1, length(y));
y_noise_filtered = medfilt1(y_noise);

Comment: @LaurentDuval,  it is actually  sinusoidal signal and my teacher ask me can value of error be zero after using medianfilt1 or 2 to filter noise in signal.

Comment: `medfilt1` exists in Matlab. Why do you said 'or 2'? What is the error: y_noise_filtered - y?

Comment: Draw signal ( x(n) ): sum of 2 sinusoidal signals with amplitudes A1, A2. (n>100) // 1 point
2. Add noise: add random noise // 1 point
3. Filter by median // 1 point
4. Displaying the error, the variance/mean of error and analyse when change A1, A2, and order of
the filter. Show results of analyse by matlab. (you can using SNR for displaying) // 2 points
5. The error can be 0 or not after filtering ? and why ? // 1 points ***
6. Displaying the histogram of the signal before and after filtering // 2 points

Comment: @LaurentDuval, that is my question in school

Comment: i have done 1,2,3,6 but i dont understand 4,5 very well

Comment: I am answering. Yet, it would be better if you update your question with what you wrote in the comments (if you can)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discrete signal is a sum of two sines. The noise is an additive uniform noise, always positive (`rand` lies in open interval $(0,1)$). The latter  is the crucial point with the median. Suppose you have a frame of three signals samples: $x_0$, $x_1$, $x_2$, and three noise realizations:  $n_0$, $n_1$, $n_2$ in $[0,1]$. So you are checking if:

$$\textrm{med}\{x_0+n_0,x_1+n_1,x_2+n_2\}-x_1$$

can be zero for each window frame. You have noticed from the plots that the noisy signal is always above the clean one. So the  median of $\{x_0+n_0,x_1+n_1,x_2+n_2\}$  is always higher than the  median of $\{x_0,x_1,x_2\}$.

But could it be the same as the initial data (putting signal borders away)? Yes. Take  $\{x_0,x_1,x_2\}=\{0,0.5,0.2\}$ and add the random realization $\{0.5,0.1,0.3\}$. Then the median of the noisy signal is $0.5$, the exact value of the center sample $x_1$.

So for some well-chosen signals and noise, their are counter-examples, a median filter can in cases provides a zero error. However, and I admit I cannot give a proof at this time, **it is probably very unlikely** that there is a zero error for  long enough generic signals.

Note to DSP folks: I feel like I am missing a very evident proof, or such a question is not adapted at this level of signal processing.